# Show table header in views (Bootstrap table)

Tags: views

I need to show header table in a view (bootstrap table) like: title, image, descripton, etc. But i can't find the option. I compare this view to an old one and everything seems normal. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: there is option in view i,e format you can select table or edit from backend http://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/modify-content-directly-using-editable-views-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your label of the row is enabled or checkbox is checked which shows `Show Label`. Go to fields in view, and click on any field, you can see that option.